# Razor pages policies not working when trying to restrict static folders

Tags: razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to restrict non-code folders. Such as /files and /swagger.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireRole("Admin");
    });
});
```

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/file/", "Admin");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/swagger/", "Admin");
});
```

I've tried it with a slash at the end and without, no difference.

In my Admin area, I have a page with "[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]" and it works just fine -- so the basics are there, I'm clearly missing something silly.

The /files is located under wwwroot and swagger is, well, swagger.

No error is given -- simply anonymous access is allowed. So it's not even trying to auth, much less check a role.

Is it possible to give a role a specific access to a path and that path not contain actual razor pages?

Comment: If you don't want people to be able to access static files, don't place them in wwwroot. That location is intended for files that should be browseable.

Comment: Good to know but that still doesn't answer my swagger problem :/